# the row can't be deleted correctly using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a table with different rows where I try to delete a single row by clicking on the "delete" button. It works but when I refresh the page by clicking on displaying tables ("Afficher les tables"), I find that the row is not deleted.

Here's my controller

```
   var app=angular.module("MyCat",[]);
app.controller("CatController",function($scope,$http){
        $scope.entities=[];
        $scope.entity={};
        $scope.currentEntity=null;
        $scope.selectedEntities=[];
        $scope.dataTypes=[];
        $scope.field={};
        $scope.fields=[];
        $scope.records=[];
        $scope.rows=[];
        $scope.action=null;
        $scope.relations=[];
    $scope.loadTables=function(){
        $http.get("/getTables")
         .success(function(data){
             $scope.entities=data;
         });
        $http.get("/getTypes")
         .success(function(data){
             $scope.dataTypes=data;
             console.log($scope.dataTypes);
         });
    };
    $scope.loadTables();
    $scope.saveTable=function(){
        $http.post("/saveTable",$scope.entity)
         .success(function(data){
             $scope.entities.push(data);
             console.log($scope.entities);
         });
    };
    $scope.getRows=function(){
        if($scope.currentEntity!=null){
        $http.get("/getAllRecords?entityID="+$scope.currentEntity.id)
         .success(function(data){
             $scope.rows=data;
             console.log($scope.rows);
         });
        }
    };
    $scope.saveField=function(){
        $scope.field.entity=$scope.currentEntity;
        $http.post("/saveField",$scope.field)
         .success(function(data){
             $scope.fields.push(data);
             console.log($scope.entities);
         });
    };


    $scope.deleteField=function(index) {

       $scope.fields.splice(index,1);



    };

     $scope.updateField = function (index) {

        };


     $scope.saveEdits = function() {
            $scope.editmode = false;
            $scope.field= angular.copy($scope.currentrow);

          };
    $scope.showFields=function(t){
        $scope.currentEntity=t;
        $http.get("/getFields?id="+t.id)
         .success(function(data){
             $scope.fields=data;
         });
        //$scope.getRows();
        $scope.action="structure";
        console.log($scope.currentEntity);
    };
    $scope.viewTables=function(){
        $scope.currentEntity=null;
    };
    $scope.saveRecord=function(){
        console.log($scope.records);
        var o={};
        o.entityID=$scope.currentEntity.id;
        o.record=[];var i=0;
        for(id in $scope.records){
            o.record[i]={};
            o.record[i].fieldID=id;
            o.record[i].value=$scope.records[id].value;
            ++i;
        }
        console.log(o);
        $http.post("/saveRecord",o)
         .success(function(data){
             console.log(data);
         });
    };
    $scope.view=function(action){
        $scope.action=action;
        if(action=='rows'){
            $scope.getRows();
        }
        else if(action=='structure'){
            $scope.showFields($scope.currentEntity);
        }
        else if(action=='form'){
            console.log("-----------");
            console.log($scope.fields);
            //$scope.showFields();
            for(item in $scope.fields){
                var f= $scope.fields[item];
                if(f.relation!=null){
                    $http.get("/getAllRecords?entityID="+f.relation.id)
                     .success(function(data){
                         $scope.relations[f.id]=data;
                     });
                }

            }
        }
    };
    $scope.deleteTables=function(){
        console.log($scope.selectedEntities);
        var t=[];
        for(item in $scope.selectedEntities){
            console.log(item)
            if($scope.selectedEntities[item].id!=false){
                t.push($scope.selectedEntities[item]);
            }
        }

        console.log(t);
            $http.post("/deleteTables",t)
             .success(function(data){
                 $scope.currentEntity={};
                 $scope.selectedEntities=[];
                 $scope.loadTables();

             });
        //}
    };
});
```

Here's my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Catalogue</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyCat" ng-controller="CatController" >

 <div ng-show="currentEntity==null">
 <div class="container spacer" >
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td><label>Nom Table:</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" ng-model="entity.entityName"></td>
       <td><button ng-click="saveTable()">Ajouter La table</button> </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  </div>
  <div class="container spacer">
   <table class="table  table-hover spacer">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><button ng-click="deleteTables()">delete</button></th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nom Table</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="t in entities track by $index" class="clickable" 
      ng-class="{active:currentEntity.id==t.id}" ng-click="showFields(t)">
       <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedEntities[$index].id" ng-true-value="{{t.id}}"/></td> 
       <td>{{t.id}}</td>
       <td>{{t.entityName}}</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>  

   </table>
  </div>
   </div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <div class="container spacer"  ng-show="currentEntity!=null">
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        Champs de la table {{currentEntity.entityName}}
        <button ng-click="viewTables()">Afficher Les tables</button>
        <button ng-click="view('structure')">Structure</button>
        <button ng-click="view('form')">Formulaire</button>
        <button ng-click="view('rows')">Rows</button>
    </div>
    <form ng-show="action=='structure'">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th><th>ID</th><th>Nom du Champs</th><th>Type</th><th>Relation</th><th>Input Type</th><td>Size</td><th>Primary</th><th>Index</th><th></th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="f in fields track by $index" class="clickable" 
      ng-class="{active:currentEntity.id==t.id}" ng-click="showFields(t)">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="field.fieldName"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="field.fieldType">
          <option ng-repeat="dt in datatypes" value="{{dt.id}}">{{dt.typeName}}</option>

          </td>


        <td> 
           <select ng-show="field.fieldType.id==6" ng-model="field.relation.id"> 
              <option value="null">----------</option> 
               <option ng-repeat="t in entities" value="{{t.id}}">
                {{t.entityName}} 
              </option> 
             </select> 
           </td> 
          <td>
            <select ng-model="field.inputType">
              <option value="text">text</option>
              <option value="checkbox">checkbox</option>
              <option value="radio">radio</option>
              <option value="radio">select</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="field.size"/></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="field.primary"/></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="field.index"/></td>
          <td><button ng-click="saveField()">Save</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="f in fields"  track by $index" class="clickable" >

<!--            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedEntities[$index].id" ng-true-value="{{f.id}}"/></td>  -->
         <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="f.editMode"/></td>
          <td><span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.id}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.id" ng-show="f.editMode"/></td>
         <td><span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.fieldName}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.fieldName" ng-show="f.editMode"/></td>
          <td><span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.fieldType.typeName}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.fieldType.typeName" ng-show="f.editMode"/></td>
          <td><span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.relation.entityName}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.relation.entityName" ng-show="f.editMode"/></td>  
          <td><span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.inputType}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.inputType" ng-show="f.editMode"/></td>
          <td><span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.size}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.size" ng-show="f.editMode"/></td>
          <td><span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.primary}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.primary" ng-show="f.editMode"/></td>
          <td><span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.index}}</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.index" ng-show="f.editMode"/></td>


          <td><button ng-click="deleteField(f)">delete</button></td> 

          <td><button ng-click="SaveEdits($index)" >saveEdits</button></td> 



        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="container" ng-show="currentEntity!=null">
    <form ng-show="action=='form'">
      <table class="table">
        <tr ng-repeat="f in fields">
          <td>{{f.fieldName}} :</td>
          <td ng-show="f.relation==null"><input type="{{f.inputType}}" ng-model="records[f.id].value"/></td>
          <td ng-show="f.relation!=null">

           <select ng-model="records[f.id].value" >
            <option ng-repeat="v in relations[f.id] track by $index" ng-value="{{v.id}}">
              {{v.id}}
            </option>
           </select>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
           <button ng-click="saveRecord()">Save</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="container" ng-show="currentEntity!=null">
    <form ng-show="action=='rows'">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th ng-repeat="f in fields">{{f.fieldName}}</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="r in rows track by $index">
           <td>{{r['id']}}</td>
           <td ng-repeat="f in fields track by f.fieldName">{{r[f.fieldName]}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my view

[image]

Comment: Where is the data coming from? You also need to delete it from the server.

Comment: i have the data stored in the model (fields) . i don' know how to update  the model

Comment: Is the data stored in some backend data store? If it's just hard coded then you won't be able to update it.

Comment: No they are not hard coded , i will update my post to show you my index.html

Comment: Can you post your full controller

Comment: you are gettinh the data from $http request you have to delete the data in the backend also then only when refreshed it will be deleted

Answer (score 0):

You are using this to get the data from the server:

```
 $http.get("/getFields?id="+t.id)
     .success(function(data){
         $scope.fields=data;
     });
```

Deleting an element from the $scope.fields array won't delete it on the source of the data. If you "delete" something you need to delete it **in the server**:

```
$http.delete("/fields", {params: {fieldId: fieldID});
```

This is just an example, you need to figure out what's the correct url for your api. Also, the way you are doing it is not very RESTful but I take it you are still learning.

Comment: here's what i have done but still not work     
 $scope.deleteField = function(f){
 $http.delete('/fields/' + field.id )
   .success(function(){
     var index = $scope.fields.indexOf(f);
     $scope.fields.splice(index,1);
   });
   
 };

Comment: Is there a way you can validate in a database or log in the server if the http request reached and was successful? I mean, what is supposed to happen is that the server delete's the record (with the appropriate code to do that) and the next time you call `'/getFields'` the deleted record should not appear